# Query Not Summing Appropriately

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I adapted this syntax to fit my need from a post from @ypercubeᵀᴹ - but in my instance shown below - the Select statement only returns the top most value for the `patientID` it does not `SUM()` the value for each `DoctorName` listed.  In this instance, I want the `SUM()` for `TotalBill` by each `DoctorName`

What is set-up wrong in the query below?

```
Declare @TotalBill Table
(
     doctorname varchar(100)
    ,patientid varchar(10)
    ,totalbill decimal(10,2)
    ,vdate date
)

Declare @HospitalInfo Table
(
     doctorname varchar(100)
    ,patientid varchar(10)
    ,vdate date
)
INSERT INTO @TotalBill (doctorname, totalbill, patientid, vdate) VALUES
('Doctor Z',    '11.48',    '4321',         '2017-01-25'),
('Doctor Z',    '11804.00', '3431',         '2017-01-31'),
('Doctor Z',    '879.40',   '1111',         '2017-01-26'),
('Doctor Z',    '11.24',    '0089',         '2017-01-26'),
('Doctor A',    '11.24',    '6654',         '2017-01-26'),
('Doctor A',    '55.11',    '0011',         '2017-01-26'),
('Doctor A',    '66.24',    '5466',         '2017-01-26'),
('Doctor A',    '22.24',    '1098',         '2017-01-26'),
('Doctor A',    '13.24',    '9987',         '2017-01-26')


Insert Into @HospitalInfo (doctorname, patientid, vdate) Values
('Doctor Z',    '1111',         '2017-01-26'),
('Doctor Z',    '0089',         '2017-01-26'),
('Doctor Z',    '3431',         '2017-01-31'),
('Doctor Z',    '4321',         '2017-01-25'),
('Doctor A',    '6654',         '2017-01-26'),
('Doctor A',    '0011',         '2017-01-26'),
('Doctor A',    '5466',         '2017-01-26'),
('Doctor A',    '1098',         '2017-01-26'),
('Doctor A',    '9987',         '2017-01-26')

Declare @Startdate datetime = '01/01/2017', @Enddate datetime = '01/31/2017'
Select
a.[doctorname]
,a.[patientid]
,[Total Bill] = COALESCE(sumTB,0)
FROM 
    ( SELECT [doctorname]
             ,patientid
             ,vdate
             ,rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.[doctorname]
                                     ORDER BY [patientid])
      FROM @HospitalInfo As a
    ) As a
    OUTER APPLY
    ( SELECT sumTB = SUM(b.[totalbill])
      FROM @TotalBill b
      WHERE a.patientid = b.patientid
      AND a.[doctorname] = b.[doctorname]
        AND a.rn = 1
    ) AS b 
WHERE CAST([vdate] As Date) BETWEEN @Startdate AND @Enddate
```

**EDIT**
My desired output is like the image below.  SUM the totalbill - and only show it for ONE patientID.  I do not care if it is a random id or the Max() or Min() as longn as it is only one

[image]

Comment: Can you give us a clue what your *desired output* looks like? I like to see rows with values rather than reverse engineer word problems.

Comment: @AaronBertrand -- see my edit.  I want the SUM(totalbill) returned, but for only one patientID.  It does not matter to me if it is a random patientID or the Min() or Max().  Whatever is easier to return.

Comment: Try removing `a.patientid = b.patientid` from the outer apply.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - that got it.  Such a simple SQL mistake, ruining my desired output.  Thank you.

Comment: Why is a join required? Seems everything in your result comes from `@TotalBill` and there is a lot of redundant info in `@HospitalInfo`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - you are correct.  It looks like all the data can be pulled from `@HospitalInfo` and there is no need for the `JOIN` - or would I do a `Self-JOIN` to still only update 1 `patientID`

Comment: Actually `@HospitalInfo` is the one that doesn't seem to be needed at all (and if some other columns from that table are needed, they be joined later). Where are you doing an update? Why? Do you want to store redundant data that will require constant maintenance?

Comment: No update is being performed.  The queries are based on views, so one the below query is run real time data is returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `a.patientid = b.patientid` from the `outer apply()` `where` clause:

```
Declare @Startdate datetime = '01/01/2017', @Enddate datetime = '01/31/2017'
Select
a.[doctorname]
,a.[patientid]
,[Total Bill] = COALESCE(sumTB,0)
FROM 
    ( SELECT [doctorname]
             ,patientid
             ,vdate
             ,rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.[doctorname]
                                     ORDER BY [patientid])
      FROM @HospitalInfo As a
    ) As a
    OUTER APPLY
    ( SELECT sumTB = SUM(b.[totalbill])
      FROM @TotalBill b
      WHERE /*a.patientid = b.patientid
      AND*/ a.[doctorname] = b.[doctorname]
        AND a.rn = 1
    ) AS b 
WHERE CAST([vdate] As Date) BETWEEN @Startdate AND @Enddate
```

results: http://rextester.com/ZWS42033

```
+------------+-----------+------------+
| doctorname | patientid | Total Bill |
+------------+-----------+------------+
| Doctor A   |      0011 | 168,07     |
| Doctor A   |      1098 | 0,00       |
| Doctor A   |      5466 | 0,00       |
| Doctor A   |      6654 | 0,00       |
| Doctor A   |      9987 | 0,00       |
| Doctor Z   |      0089 | 12706,12   |
| Doctor Z   |      1111 | 0,00       |
| Doctor Z   |      3431 | 0,00       |
| Doctor Z   |      4321 | 0,00       |
+------------+-----------+------------+
```

Comment: This is probably right. You're far less lazy about re-coding than I am.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik I'm not so sure it's this simple... I'm guessing the example data doesn't match his use case.

Comment: Well, yeah, but you have my vote anyway.

Comment: @SqlZim - see my edit.  I want to return each patientID - but SUM() the totalbill amount and display it for only one TotalBill per doctorname.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik was this your original answer that you deleted?

Comment: Nope! I pulled patientid out, assuming people wanted results that would make sense :)

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be making the query a lot more complicated than it needs to be, and while I agree with Erik that the results you want don't seem to make any logical sense (if you want total bills to a doctor, then why have individual rows for each patient?), here is a simpler way:

```
DECLARE @Startdate date = '20170101', 
        @Enddate   date = '20170131';

;WITH data AS
(
  SELECT doctorname, patientid, bill = SUM(totalbill) OVER (PARTITION BY doctorname),
    r = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY doctorname ORDER BY doctorname)
  FROM @TotalBill
  WHERE vdate >= @Startdate
    AND vdate <  DATEADD(DAY,1,@Enddate)
)
SELECT doctorname, patientid, totalbill = COALESCE(CASE r WHEN 1 THEN bill END, 0)
FROM data;
```

A couple of notes:

- don't use `datetime` for your variables when the column is `date`
- don't use messy and unnecessary `CONVERT()` functions (why convert `date` to `date`?)
- don't use unsafe regional formats like `'mm/dd/yyyy'` - [further reading](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)
- don't use `BETWEEN` for any range queries - [further reading](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

  - *(While it's true that `BETWEEN` works fine for queries only involving `date` queries, it is far too easy to copy that logic elsewhere, where it doesn't work -
    just be consistent.)*
- also see [this post about "dating responsibly"](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-dating-responsibly)